# Find next element in matrix

Tags: swift

I have simple two dimensional array with different number of elements in each row. My goal is find next element with elegant solution.

If we have the last element we should get the first one.

```
[
  [1, 0, 234, 345, 678],
  [123, 456, 789],
  [0, 9]
]

678 -> 123
9 -> 1
```

Comment: Maybe transforming the array into a single one, then doing a `firstIndex(where:)` on it, and then giving the next one? But define "elegant", because I guess you already have a working solution (which one?) that you don't find elegant?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `9 -> 0` ?

Comment: @Magnas I understood the first one (once flatten), because the last one of a sub array returns the first one of the next sub array. So 9 should return 1.

Comment: Ah ok, I see, I think.

Answer (score 1):

If `mat` is a nested array then `mat.joined()` is a “lazy flat collection” of all the nested elements. That suggest to solve the problem for *arbitrary collections:*

> Given a collection and an element of that collection, return the immediate successor of the element. The collection is viewed as *cyclic,* so that the successor of the last element is the first element.

A straight-forward implementation is (explanations inline):

```
extension Collection where Element: Comparable {
    func cyclicNext(after elem: Element) -> Element? {
        // Find (first) index of given element
        guard var idx = firstIndex(of: elem) else {
            return nil // Element not present in collection
        }
        formIndex(after: &idx) // Advance index by one
        if idx == endIndex { // If past the end ...
            idx = startIndex // ... then jump back to the start
        }
        return self[idx]
    }
}
```

If the element occurs more than once in the collection then the successor of the first occurrence is returned.

This can be applied to your matrix:

```
let mat: [[Int]] = [[1, 0, 234, 345, 678],
                    [123, 456, 789],
                    [0, 9]]

print(mat.joined().cyclicNext(after: 1))    // 0
print(mat.joined().cyclicNext(after: 678))  // 123
print(mat.joined().cyclicNext(after: 123))  // 456
print(mat.joined().cyclicNext(after: 9))    // 1
print(mat.joined().cyclicNext(after: 999))  // nil
```

It can also be applied to other collections:

```
print([1, 3, 5, 7].cyclicNext(after: 3))    // 5
print([1, 3, 5, 7].cyclicNext(after: 7))    // 1

print("Hello World".cyclicNext(after: "W")) // "o"
print("Hello World".cyclicNext(after: "d")) // "H"
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what a *flat collection* is? (preferably with some documentation)

Comment: @Carpsen90: That was perhaps not the best wording. What I meant is that `joined()` returns a lazy collection of the flattened elements. The concrete return type is [`FlattenCollection`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/flattencollection), which is a specialization of [`FlattenSequence`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/flattensequence). – The general idea is to treat the the matrix as a single (“flat”) collection of all its elements, but without actually creating a new array.

Comment: Thank you, maybe it's my wording, not yours. (Feel free to ignore this) What I'd like to know is: Do the collections returned by `joined()` (and `enumerated()` for that matter) take only the size of one element in memory? or do they eventually occupy more memory as the elements are read from the original collection? I hope this makes sense

Comment: @Carpsen90: What I *assume* is that they only store indices into the original collection. One could look at the actual implementation for the details.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to flatten your array.

Tested on Playground:

```
let mat: [[Int]] = [[1, 0, 234, 345, 678],
                    [123, 456, 789],
                    [0, 9]]

func next(element: Int, in matrix: [[Int]]) -> Int? {
    let flatten = matrix.flatMap({ $0 })
    guard let index = flatten.firstIndex(of: element) else {
        print("Element \(element) not found in matrix")
        return nil
    }
    if index == flatten.endIndex - 1 {
        return flatten.first
    } else {
        return flatten[index + 1 ]
    }
}


let result1 = next(element: 678, in: mat)
print("End of subarray Test: \(result1)")
let result2 = next(element: 9, in: mat)
print("Last one Test: \(result2)")
let result3 = next(element: 66, in: mat)
print("Not present test: \(result3)")
let result0 = next(element: 1, in: mat)
print("First one test: \(result0)")
```

Output:

```
$>End of subarray Test: Optional(123)
$>Last one Test: Optional(1)
$>Element 66 not found in matrix
$>Not present test: nil
$>First one test: Optional(0)
```

I don't know if it's enough elegant for you.
One optimization would have to keep the `flatten` and not recalculate each time.

Comment: The test `if index == flatten.last` is wrong, it works by chance in this example because the last element at index 9 happens to be 9. It should be `if index == flatten.endIndex - 1`

Comment: An alternative is to work on `matrix.joined()`, which returns a lazy collection instead of a new array.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this does do the job :

```
extension Array where Element == [Int] {
    func element(after x: Int) -> Int? {
        var arrayIndex = 0
        while arrayIndex < self.count {
            //If an array contains the searched element
            if let xIndex = self[arrayIndex].firstIndex(where: { $0 == x }) {
                //if the next element is in the same array
                if xIndex < self[arrayIndex].count - 1 {
                    return self[arrayIndex][xIndex + 1]
                }
                //if the next element is in the next array
                else if arrayIndex < self.count - 1 {
                    return self[arrayIndex + 1][0]
                }
                //if the x is the last element in the last array
                else {
                    return self[0][0]
                }
            }
            arrayIndex += 1
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

And here are some test cases :

```
let mat = [
    [1, 0, 234, 345, 678],
    [123, 456, 789],
    [0, 9]
]
mat.element(after: 678) //123
mat.element(after: 9)   //1
mat.element(after: 1)   //0
mat.element(after: 0)   //234
mat.element(after: 3)   //nil
```